# How remove "(" brackets from json in realm

Tags: json, swift, realm

Problem is with display brackets in cell. Example:

```
price: (
12
)
```

in console we see:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x6000025f6d30>(
12
)
)
```

Code:

```
if let transaction = transactions?[indexPath.row] {
    cell.textLabel?.text = " Price: \(bank.parent.value(forKey: "price") ?? "")"
}
```

Comment: `bank.parent.value(forKey: "price")` seems to be an `NSArray`. How do you want to show the array? And you need to check if `value(forKey:)` is the right method for your purpose, it is often used where it should not be.

Comment: The parentheses are not part of the JSON. That’s how `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` is represented (by its `description`). Either cast it to Swift Array and use `first` or access it as `NSArray` and use `firstObject`.

Comment: Cast as NsArray and show first object fix this problem. Solved.